# JQuery .animate() in {Chrome, Safari} != {FF, IE, Opera}

Tags: safari, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I've made a absolutely positioned  that starts centered horizontally with width=0 that expands to both sides of the page using .animate().  The effect works as intended in Firefox, Opera, and IE, but Chrome and Safari surprisingly both move the div to the left of the page (almost left=0) before expanding it to 100%.  I cannot understand why; I must be missing something.  Any suggestions to save my sanity will be forever appreciated..

```
#panel { position: absolute; top: 110px; bottom: 240px !important; min-height: 200px; width: 0; left: 50%; }

$('#panel').animate({'left': '0', 'width': '100%'}, 750);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but now it is working fine. It is fixed in the latest version of jquery.
You just have to take the latest version of jquery 1.4.3. and replace it 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js